# Segmentationfault error

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to compile this program in Linux with a makefile but the output shows

```
make: ***[run] segmentation fault
```

My code is:

```
int removeblanks(char string[], char temp[]){
    int i, j=0; printf("no");
    while(string[i] != '\0'){
        if (string[i] != ' ') {
            temp[j] = string[i];
            printf("%c\n",temp[j]);
            j++;
       }
       i++;
   }
   temp[j] = '\0';
   return i;
}

int palindromos(int size, char temp[]) {
    int i,palindromo=1; int middle= size/2;
    for(i=0; i<middle; i++) {
        if(temp[i]!=temp[size]){
            palindromo= 0;
        }
        size--;
    }
    return palindromo;
}

int main() {
    char string1[30] ="Anotaram a data da maratona";
    char string2[30]="A torre da derrota";
    char temp1[30];
    char temp2[30];
    printf("frase 1: %s\n", string1);
    printf("frase 2: %s\n", string2);
    int size1=0;
    size1=removeblanks(string1,temp1);
    printf("size1: %d",size1);
    int size2=removeblanks(string1,temp1);
    int palindromo1=palindromos(size1, string1);
    int palindromo2=palindromos(size2, string2);
    printf("As frases sao palindromos.\n");
    printf("As frases nao sao palindromos.\n");
    return 1;
}
```

I don't know how to debug and find the error. Can someone help me?

Comment: int palindromos(int size, char temp[]){int i,palindromo=1;
 int middle= size/2;
 for(i=0; i<middle; i++){
  if(temp[i]!=temp[size]){
   palindromo= 0;
  }
  size--;
 }   
 return palindromo;
}

Comment: int removeblanks(char string[], char temp[]){
   int i, j=0;
   printf("no");
  while(string[i] != '\0'){
    if (string[i] != ' ') {
       temp[j] = string[i];
       printf("%c\n",temp[j]);
       j++;
    }
    i++;
}
  temp[j] = '\0';
  return i;
}

Comment: You mean the `make` run segfaults?

Comment: Please do not add code here in comments. It is impossible to read that. There is an `edit` button right below your question...

Comment: yes when i use in the terminal make run the output is : make: *** [run] Segmentation fault

Comment: Ah, ok, you use `make` to _run_ the program. So it is _not_ make that segfaults, but the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In function `int removeblanks(char string[], char temp[])`-

```
int i, j=0; printf("no");             // i declared not initialized
while(string[i] != '\0'){             // uninitialized local variable used here
...
}
```

You should initialize `i=0` before using it.